# Product Media Tab not allowing to add Media

Tags: product, b2b-commerce

I am new to B2B Commerce Lightning and I am trying to add Media to Products, but Media Product Tab only shows this message three times:

"There was a problem getting the media group record. Your Salesforce admin can help with that."

[image]

I have follow all the steps in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=b2b_commerce.htm&type=5 to set up my B2B Commerce and give extra permissions to System Admin profile to view/edit/delete Product Media but the problem persists.

And I cannot ask my admin for help because I am the admin...

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try capturing a debug log for that page? That may unearth a better error message in a log. Feel free to share it here and we can help you solve it.

Comment: Hi! I already solved. It is a Known Issue and the only way to solve it is to open a Case to Salesforce and allowing them access to your org.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Can you share with us what informations you included in the Case (not the infos, obviously, but the kind of infos). Did you add something more than what you wrote here? Thanks a lot. Daniel.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I wrote a case to salesforce with screenshots of the "empty" product media tab and refer to the following link in a forum in which the user explains the problem  https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A000000HWXU&fId=0D54S000008iNhd (Answer by Franco Llamas)

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I found is - Log a Case to Salesforce Support and only they can help you with this.

I had the same issue and they told me that they had to run some scripts to get it.